# Template instantiation with undefined member function return types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, auto

```
struct Value {
    using a_type = int;
    a_type f() { return 1; }
};

template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    T t;
    auto call_f() { return t.f(); }
};

int main() {
    Wrapper<Value> w;
    Wrapper<int> w2;
    w.call_f();
}
```

This compiles fine on Clang and GCC. `Wrapper<int>` gets instantiated even though the return type of `Wrapper<int>::call_f()` can not be deduced (there is no `int::f()`). It fails only when `w2.call_f()` gets called.

Is this part of the C++ standard, and can it be expected to work on all compilers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is part of the C++ standard.

The rules of template instantiation are long and complex, but the short version is that a member function of a template class is only instantiated when needed. If nothing calls it, or tries to take a pointer to it, or explicitly instantiates it (and probably a few other cases that I'm forgetting), then it won't be instantiated and your code is well-formed.

As @dyp points out, it is only the *declaration* of the member function which is instantiated when the class definition is instantiated (`[temp.inst]/1`), but the return type deduction is only carried out when the function *definition* is instantiated (`[dcl.spec.auto]/12`).

This is extremely helpful both for minimising the overhead of templates and being permissive about type requirements. It's this feature which lets you do something like this:

```
struct Foo {
    //no default constructor
    Foo(int);
};

std::vector<Foo> foos;
```

Some `std::vector` functions (`resize`, for example) require `T` to be default-constructible, but as long as you don't call those functions you can still use other features of `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's guaranteed by the standard. `Wrapper<T>::call_f()` will be implicitly instantiated only when it gets called.

[$14.7.1/2 Implicit instantiation
[temp.inst]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#2):

> Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist;

[$14.7.1/8 Implicit instantiation
[temp.inst]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#8):

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a variable template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member class, a static data member of a class template, or a substatement of a constexpr if statement ([stmt.if]), unless such instantiation is required.